# Creating a formula field using IF statement with Text return

Tags: formula-field, if

I am creating a Formula field that returns texts when:

1. 1Picklist_Status = Activated, the return text should be A else
   null
2. 2Picklist_Status = Sold, the return should be B else null
3. 1Picklist_Status = ChangeofMind , the return should be C else
   null

So these are 2 picklist fields that would update the formula field if a OR b is true. The problem here is that my return type is text, so I can't use OR parameter. pls help

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you would include the formula that you've tried to write so far. Using `OR()` should work regardless of the formula return type, but you might be using it incorrectly. Showing us the formula you currently have would make it easy to see any such issues. You should [edit] your question to include that.

Answer (score 1):

If they are different fields:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Field1, 'value1'), 'A',
IF(ISPICKVAL(Field2, 'value2'), 'B',
IF(ISPICKVAL(Field3, 'value3'), 'C',
null)))
```

If they are the same field:

```
CASE(Field, 'value1','A','value2','B','value3','C',null)
```